# Azure DevOps devenv.com /Build Error Creating Window Handle

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, azure-devops, devenv

When trying to build a solution/project of SQL Server Integration Services projects in a pipeline using the Command Line task I receive the error "Error creating window handle" for certain projects in my solution. If I use the /Project switch to specify a project different to the one that errors I still get the same error.

This only occurs when trying to build from Azure DevOps using the private agent. Executing the same command when logged onto the server where the agent is hosted produces no error when I build the solution or a specific project.

I get the same error when trying to perform the same build using https://github.com/mmajcica/DevEnvBuild

Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3 is installed on the server along with SQL Server Data Tools 2015 17.4

Anyone encountered this issue before and has a solution or suggestions on how to diagnose further?

```
##[section]Starting: Command Line Script
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
Version      : 2.142.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "C:\agent\_work\27\s\Packages.sln" /Build Dev /Project "ESR\Packages.ESR.dtproj"
##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\agent\_work\_temp\a5ed53fe-bc18-4636-9db4-8797815eaf1a.cmd""


Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25420.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
C:\agent\_work\27\s\SexualHealth.Pathology\Packages.SexualHealth.Pathology.dtproj : error  : Error creating window handle.




One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'.
##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script
```

Answer (score 0):

We have seen something similar to this. It seems to be something to do with the path and the \s\ subfolder in C:\agent_work\27\s...

We found that just running devenv from a CMD line to this solution failed. changing the folder name to something other than "s" seemed to work. Not sure if it is being seen as some sort of switch or what?

Now looking to see if we can change the agent source folder name...

Hope this helps your debugging efforts.